# Google Sheets - Repeat Each Value N Times with different N value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to repeat the words for N times but different N value for each items.
For example in this picture is the desired output:

[image]

My current formula for this but I don't know how to make the N value into unique

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(IF(SEQUENCE(1,C3),B3:B1000)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A3&"@",B1:B3),"@"))),"where Col1 is not null")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, it works!! Been struggling this for 2 days.